# how to get events information out of event store request access

Tags: ios, swift5, eventkit

I am using the following code to request access to the users calendar to get their schedules.

```
   '''// Initialize the store.
    let eventStore = EKEventStore()
    // Request access to reminders.
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { granted, error in
        // Handle the response to the request.
        
        var result = ""
        if granted{
            var titles :[String] = []
            var begin : [Date] = []
            var end : [Date] = []
            let today = Date()
            let tomorrow = NSDate(timeInterval: 24 * 3600, since: today as Date) as Date
            
            
            let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: today, end: tomorrow, calendars: nil)
            
            let events = eventStore.events(matching: predicate)
            print ("events: \(events.count)")
            for event in events{
                titles.append(event.title)
                begin.append(event.startDate)
                end.append(event.endDate)
            }
            if titles.isEmpty{
                result =  "today does not have any schedule"
            }
            else{
                for index in 0...(titles.count - 1){
                    result += "Schedule " + String(index + 1) + ":\n"
                    result += "\t\(titles[index]) from \(begin[index]) to \(end[index])"
                }
            }
            
            print(result) // result = "today..." or "schedule ..."
            
        }
        print(result) // result = ""
    }'''
```

Where I don't understand is why I cannot get information of result outside of request access function, and how can I get it so I can return and send this information to another function

Comment: `requestAccess` works asynchronously. Do the things you have to do inside the closure or use a completion handler.

Comment: I tried to change `granted, error` to  `(granted, error) -> String`, but I got "Declared closure result 'String' is incompatible with contextual type 'Void'" error. Can you give me an example like how to use completion handler or how to fix this error? THX!

Comment: It depends on the enclosing method. Please search for completion handler. There are countless examples. And you cannot change the signature of a system framework API.